# Expression tree to split property value

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I am working with linq expression trees (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397951.aspx) to create complex, dynamically created custom filters.
Now I need to create an expression, that compares not the property of my table, but
every part of my split property.

The corresponding static linq statement would be:

```
myContext.MyEntityCollection
 .Where(item => item.MyProperty != null)
 .AsEnumerable<MyEntity>()
 .Select(item => item.MyProperty.Split(new[] { ',' })
 .Where( .. my filter ..)
```

E.g. on this input

```
Table MyEntity
Id          MyProperty
-----------------------------------
1           part1,part2,part3,part4
2           part5,part6
```

I want to search for "part3" and get the first row.

How to create the lambda expression for the split func<>?

**UPDATE**: That's the status I got so far (at the last line I get stuck). Also I was trying to built the expression tree from the linq statement above with the ExpressionTreeViewer but it does not work, I think because of the ".AsEnumerable".

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ReportIndex), "MyEntity");
MemberExpression stringProperty = Expression.Property(param, "MyProperty");
MethodInfo mi = typeof(string).GetMethod("Split", new[] { typeof(char[]) });
MethodCallExpression splitExpression = 
    Expression.Call(exDateProperty, mi, Expression.Constant(new[] { '|' }));
MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(ICollection<string>).GetMethod("Contains");
var expression = Expression.Call(param, containsMethod, splitExpression, stringProperty);
```

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Contains("part3"));`

Comment: @Rune FS: Why did you change the title? I am not interested to get the linq query. That's simple. I need really the linq expression statements.

Comment: What are "linq expression statements"? :|

Comment: It's not an expression tree your are looking for. An expression tree is a computational representation of a statement. Ie that's when you use code to build up code dynamically

Comment: I am referring to expression trees that can be used as linq provider. See 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397951.aspx

Comment: @Rune FS: But that's what I need. I create the code dynamically. Only with the linq statement of above, I have problems to convert it to an expression tree.

Comment: Then post the part of the Expression tree building you have done instead of the code you wish to represent with that expression tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, I think it is not possible to do with expression trees.
What I finally did, was to change my data model.

**UPDATE** Since there is no new input for one week, I set this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where( t => t.Any(i => i=="part3"))
```

Comment: A little explanation as to how and why your answer could work would be nice. Now it's just a piece of code.

Answer (score -1):

To get the item matching the given criteria use:

```
var rows = myContext.MyEntityCollection
    .Where(item => item.MyProperty != null)
    .AsEnumerable<MyEntity>()
    .FirstOrDefault(item => item.MyProperty.Contains("part3"));
```

To get all matching rows:

```
var rows = myContext.MyEntityCollection
    .Where(item => item.MyProperty != null)
    .AsEnumerable<MyEntity>()
    .Where(item => item.MyProperty.Contains("part3"));
```

Or if you from some reason need to use `Split`:

```
var rows = myContext.MyEntityCollection
    .Where(item => item.MyProperty != null)
    .AsEnumerable<MyEntity>()
    .Where(item => item.MyProperty.Split(new[] { ',' }).Contains("part3"));
```

A bit more clear version:

```
var rows = myContext.MyEntityCollection
    .Where(item => item.MyProperty != null)
    .AsEnumerable<MyEntity>()
    .Select(item => new 
        {
            Item = item,
            Parts = item.MyProperty.Split(new[] { ',' })
        })
    .Where(itemWithParts => itemWithParts.Parts.Contains("part3"))
    .Select(itemWithParts => itemWithParts.Item);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want:

```
myContext.MyEntityCollection
    .Where(item => item.MyProperty != null)
    .AsEnumerable<MyEntity>()
    .Where(item => item.MyProperty.Split(new [] { ',' }).Any(p => p == "part3"));
```